# Objective C framework for swift app, error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I am building an objective C framework for a swift app. I am trying to use a function in swift by an objective C header file that is imported.

```
interface MyApi : NSObject

+ (void)init:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;

@end
```

```
@implementation MyApi

+ (void)init:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ...
}
@end
```

These are the .h and .m files in obj C. In swift I am trying to call the function like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        MyApi.init(launchOptions)
        return true
    }
```

But I keep getting the error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

at the line I am calling the function.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax:

```
MyApi.init(launchOptions)
```

calls the *initialiser* of `MyApi`. Note that `init` is a keyword in Swift and has special meaning! Since `MyApi` inherits from `NSObject`, it inherits the parameterless initialiser, which is what the Swift compiler *thinks* that you are trying to call. This is the same as:

```
MyApi(launchOptions)
```

However, your `init` method in Objective-C is not an initialiser for a `MyApi` object, is it? It's just a regular class method called `init`. To call it in Swift, you have to escape the special meaning of the `init` keyword by adding backticks around it:

```
MyApi.`init`(launchOptions)
```

The backticks are quite [astonishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), so I'd suggest that you rename `init` to something else, like `setup`.

Comment: I'd rename the Objective-C method though, or provide a different syntax on Swift. But even on Objective-C, I would have renamed it since it's a little confusing.